# Adding "values" to a texfield in jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

When writing a new email, I've got a modal(pop-up window in boostrap) that shows a list of contacts. When I select (through checkboxes) a couple of contacts, the selected ones are written into a checkbox. Problem is I'm just writing the lastone I select instead of all of the selected ones.

If you need further explanation please ask. (Sorry for my english)

```
 $("#tblContacto").on("click", ".ck", function(event){      
    if($(".ck").is(':checked')) {  
        selected_index = parseInt($(this).attr("alt").replace("Check", ""));
        var contacto = JSON.parse(tbContactos[selected_index]);

        $("#txtDestinatarios").val(contacto.Email);
    } else {  
        $("#txtDestinatarios").val("");
    }  
});
```

Comment: Can you show jsfiddle?

Comment: Im trying to set up a jsfiddle but the modal is not working properly. As soon as i get it working, ill update.

Comment: Have you more details? Have you tried " if($(this).is(':checked')) "  for check just the element clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set all selected items in the checkboxes into Textfiled you can use the following line of code :-

```
 $("#txtDestinatarios").val( $("#txtDestinatarios").val()+ ","+contacto.Email);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to add all E-Mails into a textfield with id `txtDestinatarios`the cause of your Problem is the usage of the `$("#txtDestinatarios").val();` function.

Calling `val()` with an argument sets (and thus overwrites) the value within the textfield. (See demo at http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2)

You would have to first retrieve the value of the textfield using code like `var currentValue = $("#txtDestinatarios").val()` and then add/remove the E-Mail from/to the string before setting the resulting string back as the value.